Wondering how to update value in json file with command
Can't get my bot to change data after a command is executed. It saves the pre set data but doesnt make changes. Does anyone know how to make it so when the command is executed it Adds +1 to "Log_Number" and saves it to the JSON file
THE COMMAND:
class Weed(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    ## Data Check

    async def dataExists(ctx):
        try:`
            with open(Weed_Data, 'r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                print("[Data Loaded]")
                return data
        except:
            await ctx.send('**[ERROR]** File __"'+ Weed_Data +'"__ doesn\'t exist')
            return


@commands.command()
    async def growlog(self, ctx, *, message = None):
        data = await Weed.dataExists(ctx)
        if message  == None:`
            await ctx.send("Failed To Send Grow Log -> [Include Message]")
            return
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(data["logchannel_id"])
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'<:weed:757471331645128775> Grow Log - {data["Log_Number"]}', description=message, color= discord.Color.orange(), timestamp = datetime.now())
            embed.set_footer(text=f'• Grow Log')
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            log_number = int(data["Log_Number"])
            log_number += 1                     # ** <-- Trying to add 1 to log number**
            with open(Weed_Data, 'w') as j:
                json.dump(data, j, indent = 4)                 # **<-- Can't Get command to change data in .json file**
                print("  - [Data Saved]")

JSON FILE:
Pre set Log Number, can't get it to update after command
{
    "Log_Number": 1,
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you re-paste your code, and instead of using `this` on every line, add ``` above and below your entire block of code. The formatting guide has more info on how to format code.

I changed it, does this problem make sense?

update data["Log_Number"] += 1

To be clear, the idea behind your code is that you will load some data, change the data and write it back into your file? In your own words, what part of your code do you expect to change the data; and why do you expect the data to change when that code runs?

You have to update directly in data which you save.
data["Log_Number"] += 1

or you have to assign new value
data["Log_Number"] = log_number

because when you have  int or str then log_number = ... copies value to new variable and it doesn't change original data["Log_Number"]

And if you keep it as string then
data["Log_Number"] = str(int(data["Log_Number"]) + 1)

but your json file suggests that it is integer value and you don't have to use int() and str()
